# How to convert a gradle project back to normal android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I screwed up and thought that it would be a good idea to try to convert my project into a gradle project without having any knowledge of how that system works. I converted the project inside of eclipse by using "configure > convert to gradle project".  When that didn't work I made the mistake of that hitting "configure > convert to maven project" which made things 10x worse.  What is the best way for me to convert the project back to how it was before, so I can learn gradle before messing around with my project.

Comment: Ironically enough, Android Studio will import an Eclipse project without doing any conversion now, so all that was for naught.

Comment: You use version control system and can revert back to last working state, right? If not consider this to be a hint to start using one.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project -> Gradle -> Disable Gradle Nature (in eclipse luna)

Comment: Please elaborate on this and explain what it does and why that helps so the asker can understand better.